# How to configure SNI passthrough for Istio Egress

Tags: istio

I'm trying to follow the instructions described at https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/wildcard-egress-hosts/#setup-egress-gateway-with-sni-proxy but the actual command

```
    cat <<EOF | istioctl manifest generate --set values.global.istioNamespace=istio-system -f - > ./istio-egressgateway-with-sni-proxy.yaml
   .
   .
   .
```

fails . I generated an istio issue but no concrete workaround so far. Issue at https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/21379

Comment: Based on this [github istio issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/19792) 
I would say now it's only possible to do through helm and it's should be possible to do it via istioctl in 1.5 version. So workaround for now would be to use helm instead of istioctl or wait for the 1.5 version which might actually fix that. Let me know if that answer your question.

Comment: I tried it via istioctl extracted from 1.5 and it doesn't work either

Comment: Take into consideration that official release date for Istio 1.5 release is March 5th and that above issue is still open, so it might be not ready in some beta releases, it might be ready in official release in few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments

> Based on this [github istio issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/19792) I would say now it's only possible to do through helm and it's should be possible to do it via istioctl in 1.5 version. So workaround for now would be to use helm instead of istioctl or wait for the 1.5 version which might actually fix that.

and  @Vinay B  add

> The workaround right now, as @jt97 suggested is to use helm 2.x to generate the yaml
>
> Refer to https://archive.istio.io/v1.2/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/wildcard-egress-hosts/#setup-egress-gateway-with-sni-proxy as an example

is actually the only workaround for now.

If you're looking for informations when it's gonna be available via istioctl then follow this [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/19792) which is currently open and it's added to 1.5 milestone, so there is a chance it will be available when 1.5 comes out, which is March 5th.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround right now, as @jt97 suggested is to use helm 2.x to generate the yaml

Refer to https://archive.istio.io/v1.2/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/wildcard-egress-hosts/#setup-egress-gateway-with-sni-proxy as an example